# Modal Dialog read params server side

Tags: 2010, modal-dialog, codebehind

I have an applicationPage who is open by Modal Dialog. I would like to read this params server side in the application page . 
I don't use the URL for passing parameter, i use the **options.args**

Is it possible??

sample code :

Javascript :

```
var options = {
  url: '/_layouts/MyApplicationPage.aspx',
  title: 'Title',  
  autoSize: true,   
  args: { arg1: 'arg 1', arg2: 123, arg3 : 'other arg'} // My params
};
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

Server side of MyApplicationPage.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){   
  // how to read arg1, arg2, arg3 ??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably won't be able to get the args in code-behind when you specify them within the options object. When working with the options object in Modal Dialog the args will be saved on client side only. Thus the server cannot get them.

To get these args you should modify your url like this:

```
var options = {
  url: '/_layouts/MyApplicationPage.aspx' + '?arg1=arg%201&arg2=123&arg3=other%20arg',
  title: 'Title',  
  autoSize: true,   
  args: { arg1: 'arg 1', arg2: 123, arg3 : 'other arg'}
};
```

This way you can get them with `Request.Form["arg1"]`
As you can see, I did escape the arguments.

Comment: yes, that what I have done to unblock me. Pass params in URL and read it with **Request.QueryString["arg1"]**

Comment: So to answer at my question, you can't read parameter (args) of Modal Dialog in C# :-(

Answer (score 0):

Please try below line to get `args` from modal dialog

```
Request.Form["args"]
```

You can refer below mentioned link to get some more idea on it.

[SharePoint: How to pass parameters into a Modal Dialog Window and then access them](http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/2012/08/sharepoint-how-to-access-the-parameters-passed-into-a-modal-dialog-window/)

Please let me know if it does not work.

Comment: Thanks ! But the Request.Form["args"] is empty. The Application Page with the showModalDialog is open with GET methode not POST. I already read your link, You can read params with JavaScript Object Model but not in server side :-(

Comment: What happened? why "but the"?